# If one fits a linear model with just one $x_i$ then does this mean df=1-2=-1?

Tags: bayesian, degrees-of-freedom

If one fits a linear model with just one $x_i$ then does this mean that the number of degrees of freedom $=1-2=-1$?

For a linear model the degrees of freedom is:

$${\rm df}=n-k$$

where $k$ is number of coefficients. I.e. in $a+bx_i$ it's two ($a$ and $b$).

But e.g. Student $t$ is not defined for df $\le 0$.

Comment: I see the matter this way. Suppose you have one observation and $y = 42, x = 7$. Then the simplest model is $y = 42$ and this fits perfectly. If you want to regard this as $y = 42 + 0x$ that is fine, but the zero isn't being estimated at the same time; it follows necessarily from the data. There is really only one parameter to estimate, and so no degrees of freedom. (Otherwise as with @Christoph Hanck's answer, the idea of fitting a straight line is moot as there are too many solutions and nothing to choose between them.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is a way to see it, as the system will be underdetermined in that there is in infinite number of lines you could send through that single point. There would be one and only one line to connect two points (so zero d.f.). With more observations than regressors, we may start thinking about an "optimal" line, such as the linear regression slope.